# Get OS From An External Storage In Python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I know that I can get the Operating System by typing `import platform
print platform.system(), platform.release()`, but if I have an external storage ( Hard Disk ) that contains for example Linux ( It can be any other OS like Windows or Mac ), What exactly do I do to get the OS??

In other words, I want some code that tells me that this Hard Disk contains this OS.

Thanks in Advance

---

UPDATE:

It seems that my question is unclear, so I will explain it in other words.

If I import the `platform` module and printed `platform.system()` and `platform.release()`, it shows me :

> Windows 7

I want some code that gives me the same result but for attached external Hard Disks, that can contains any OS.

At the end, I want to get it's output.

So, if my Hard Disk contains FOR EXAMPLE Windows XP, it prints me:

> Windows XP

And so on.

I think that this is the simpler way to describe my question.

Comment: Just what do you mean by "external storage that contains for example Linux"? If you mean a hard drive that was formatted by a Linux system, you could find the file system used on that drive. That will not tell you the OS for sure, since some file systems can be made by multiple OSs. If you mean a computer linked to yours over the network, you could just ask the computer what its OS is. If you mean a drive that contains the files to run Linux, you could search for key files used by the OS.

Comment: What I meant is that I have a Hard Disk that contains Linux and I wanted to know what is the OS, like for example `Linux 4.4.21-v7+`

Comment: Do you mean the drive contains the files to run Linux--it could be used as the boot drive for a Linux system?

Comment: Yes, I mean a drive that contains all the files to run Linux.
And I forget to mention it, it doesn't have to be just a Linux OS, it can be a Mac or Windows. The important thing for me is that I want to write some code that tells me that this Hard Disk contains Windows and this one contains for example Linux. That is all what I want.